# horizon mapping in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor, coordinates

I am rendering a scene using cycle and I have set up a background with a *Sky texture*. Now I want to adjust the height of the horizon. I tried to use a *Mapping* node but what it does is changing the background in a solid color (which varies depending on the Z value).

Answer (score 5):

This didn't work because the `Texture Coordinates` node wasnt added. You should plug one of its output sockets (e.g. `Generated` or `Object`) into the `Vector` input socket of the `Mapping` node (this is a common approach if texturing anything in Cycles. Otherwise, in Cycles, texture won't appear on the mesh, just solid base color).

[image]

Thus you'll be able to adjust the position of the horizon simply by changing Location value by Z axis of the Mapping node (not sure if this is good idea to manipulate horizon like that).

[image]

(I changed `Location` value to `0.3` here).

Comment: Wow your Blender theme . . . how do you use it? It is very dark and overly contrasted, almost impossible to read quickly.

Comment: The contrast from the very saturated bright orange and the tremendously black background is a bit much for my eyes. I'm just surprised you can use it effectually. I think Science Lab and Elysiun are the best themes, so you can get a feel for what my personal preference is.

Comment: Back to Black is not the only option . . . it is my personal least favorite :P Oh well, this discussion is a tad off topic here I imagine